# MSACCESS - At most one record can be returned by this subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access

Please help me fix this SQL Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [ClassSessions].Shortcode
    ,[CertIV_BC_A].ID
    ,[CertIV_BC_A].Units
    ,[CertIV_BC_A].AT
    ,Format((
            SELECT DATE
            FROM ClassSessions
            WHERE [ClassSessions].[Code] = [CertIV_BC_A].[SessionStart]
                AND ([ClassSessions].[OccurenceID] = '34849')
            ), 'dd/mm/yy') AS StartDate
    ,[CertIV_BC_A].SessionStart
    ,[CertIV_BC_A].SessionEnd
FROM CertIV_BC_A
    ,ClassSessions
WHERE (([ClassSessions].[OccurenceID] = '34849'))
ORDER BY [CertIV_BC_A].ID;
```

These are the 2 databases: 
 
**CertIV_BC_A**[Cert IV_BC_A_Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6qKP.png)

**ClassSessions**
[ClassSessions Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWUYO.png)

The Query work when there is only 1 OccurenceID in ClassSessions Database. However when there are more than 1 OccurenceID in ClassSessions, I get the error.

This is the result of the query
Module  ID  AT  StartDate   EndDate

- List item
- Module 1 1   AT1 5/10/2017   31/05/2017
- Module 1 2   AT2 24/05/2017  26/06/2017
- Module 1 3   AT3
- Module 1 4   AT4
- Module 1 5   AT5
- Module 2 6   AT1 28/06/2017  28/08/2017
- Module 2 7   AT2 28/06/2017  8/07/2017

Please let me know if I need to supply more details. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select top 1 or max date from your subquery

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  [ClassSessions].Shortcode,
  [CertIV_BC_A].ID,
  [CertIV_BC_A].Units,
  [CertIV_BC_A].AT,
  Format(
   (SELECT
    MAX(Date)
    FROM ClassSessions
    WHERE [ClassSessions].

   [Code] = [CertIV_BC_A].[SessionStart]
    AND ([ClassSessions].[OccurenceID] = '34849')), 'dd/mm/yy') AS StartDate,
  [CertIV_BC_A].SessionStart,
  [CertIV_BC_A].SessionEnd

FROM CertIV_BC_A,
     ClassSessions
WHERE (([ClassSessions].[OccurenceID] = '34849'))

ORDER BY [CertIV_BC_A].ID;
```

Comment: It works... I was trying to put max everywhere, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the `Format` inside the subquery.

```
,(
    SELECT Format(DATE, 'dd/mm/yy')
    FROM ClassSessions
    WHERE [ClassSessions].[Code] = [CertIV_BC_A].[SessionStart]
        AND ([ClassSessions].[OccurenceID] = '34849')
  ) AS StartDate
```

Comment: It does look better (is more readable), but still returns multiple values where just one is expected